# Childnodes multiple javascript XML

Tags: javascript, xml, dom

Can't get chosen child when trying to pull out of XML - in this case it is author:

```
<book category="WEB">
<title lang="en">XQuery Kick Start</title>
<author>James McGovern</author>
<author>Per Bothner</author>
<author>Kurt Cagle</author>
<author>James Linn</author>
<author>Vaidyanathan Nagarajan</author>
<year>2003</year>
<price>49.99</price>
</book>
```

I can't get the javascript script to display my chosen author. Meaning that if I do this.

```
txt=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("title")[2].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
document.write("<p>"+txt);
```

I get 'James McGovern'. But

```
txt=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("title")[2].childNodes[1].nodeValue;
document.write("<p>"+txt);
```

Will not give me 'Per Bothner'. How can I make this possible?

Comment: `<author>` tags are not childNodes of the `<title>` tag in this case, so you should ask yourself why the first query is working...  Are you sure this is the complete XML document?

Comment: When you are *querying* data from XML, jQuery can come in handy because of its highly expressive querying capabilities. It's not limited to HTML. If you have the option to use jQuery, it would be a nice way to get around using flaky expressions like `[2].childNodes[1]`... Of course you would first have to inject your XML into DOM (into an invisible container).

Answer (score 0):

while i'm wondering how you obtained your result, too ... the `childNodes` array does not only contain elements but (among others) also text nodes, namely line separators (CR/LF). therefore you'd have to iterate through the array checking the node type of each entry. a better choice is using xpath to select the interesting elements, [this article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Introduction_to_using_XPath_in_JavaScript) should get you started.

specifically, `/book/author` will select exactly the, well, `author`nodes in document order.